# How do I customize Jquery Accordion UI

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-accordion

As Shown below height of accordion panel is set 230 but **why when webpage open its height remain default?** and when I move mouse over it then its height resize according to defined.

And see **Why background colour is also according to their default behaviour?** and after some height it apply my colour(ie white).

[image: NO RED LINES!]

Comment: whats the actual question being asked?

Comment: Its highlighted now in bold text

Comment: for handling the css associated with the component site http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/ you should read the theming tab.

Answer (score 0):

Height issue solved it like this..

```
 $(".accordion").accordion({
        fillSpace: true,
        event: "mouseover",
        clearStyle: true,
        autoHeight: false,
        active: 99
    }).accordion('activate', 0);
```

Background Issue Solution

```
$(".accordion .panel")
.removeClass("ui-widget-content")
.removeClass("ui-accordion-content")
.removeClass("ui-helper-reset")
.removeClass("ui-corner-bottom")
.removeClass("ui-accordion-content-active")
```

Comment: You can space-delimit more than one class to remove them all in one `removeClass()` also.